# Passing a variable in redirect in Django

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to pass a variable using the redirect function, but it is returning none.

```
def one:
    # define location variable here
    return redirect(getting_started_info, location=location)

def getting_started_info(request, location=''):
    location = location
    ...
```

Why is the variable in the redirect not passing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('getting_started_info', kwargs={'location': location}))
```

Comment: Do I need to modify my urls.py because of the argument?

Comment: This answer is literally a single line of code. You need to put more work into explaining why it works because this is a community of people looking to learn, not just make things work.

Answer (score 12):

Remember that `redirect()` isn't doing a direct call to your view, it's actually sending the client's browser a `302 Found` status (`301 Moved Permanently` if you use `permanent=True`)  with an instruction to redirect to a different URL.  In this case, that URL is one that resolves to the `getting_started_info` view.

I believe that for this to work, there must exist a urlconf which maps to `getting_started_view` and which uses its `location` positional argument.  This will most likely occur through [named groups](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#named-groups).

From the django 1.8 docs [entry](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) on `redirect()`:

> The arguments could be:
>
> - A model: the model’s get_absolute_url() function will be called.
> - A view name, possibly with arguments: urlresolvers.reverse will be used to reverse-resolve the name.
> - An absolute or relative URL, which will be used as-is for the redirect location.

Answer (score 2):

you may also pass a value of some variable using sessions or cookie.